# Set indent Unit for CodeMirror

Tags: codemirror

I want to set indentUnit to x spaces instead of the default two in CM 6

Here is my attempt to set it to 10 in a JSON viewer I am working on:

```
let state = EditorState.create({
          extensions: [
            basicSetup,       
            json({ jsx: true }),     
            indentUnit.of("          "),
            tabSize.of(EditorState.tabSize.of(10))
          ]
        })
        
        let view = new EditorView({
          state,
          parent: document.body
        })
```

but it does not work, is there anyone who can provide an example and fix my attempt above?